# How to make json array and object using checkbox in formfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here i have one form and one form fields , that is checkbox,after checking the the three fields i want to make JSON format , but i am not able do this,if anyone one know please update my answer.

```js
function rentfunction(){
var arr1 = [];
   $.each($("input[name='furniture_check']:checked"),function(){
   var furniture = $(this).val();
   arr1.push(furniture); 
   });

    var data =   {
    "rentProperty" :{
     "furnitureType" :arr1,
    }
   }
   console.log(data);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Ward robe">Ward robe <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Lights">Lights <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Fan">Fan <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Fridge">Fridge <br><br><br>
  
  <button type="button" id="rentBtnSubmit" onclick="rentfunction()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> expected answer

**suppose i am clicking Ward robe & Lights & Fridge and i am clicking the submit button means i want to make json like this**

```
{
        "rentProperty": 
        {
        "fullName" : "Some Name"
        },
        "floorType": [
                        {
                            "floorTypeName": "Ward robe"
                        },
                        {
                             "floorTypeName" :"Lights"
                        },
                        {
                             "floorTypeName" :"Fridge"
                        }
                    ]
    }
```

I am also tried but i am not able to make expected JSON format,i am getting results  like this

```
    {
  "rentProperty": {
    "furnitureType": [
      "Ward robe",
      "Lights",
      "Fan"
    ]
  }


  }
```

Comment: Why do you generate `furnitureType` in your code, when that property occurs nowhere in your desired output!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the modified code for your desired output:

```
    function rentfunction(){
    var arr1 = [];
    var data={
            "rentProperty": {
                            "fullName" : "Some Name"
                            },
            "floorType":[]
        };
                $.each($("input[name='furniture_check']:checked"),function(){
                var furniture = $(this).val();
                arr1.push({"floorTypeName": furniture }); 
                });

             data.floorType=arr1;
            //or data["floorType"]=arr1;

                console.log(data);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could get your desired output:

```js
$('#rentBtnSubmit').click(function () {
    var data = {
        rentProperty: {
            name: "some name"
        },
        floorType: $.map($("input[name=furniture_check]:checked"), function(chkbox){
            return { floorTypeName: $(chkbox).val() };
        })
    };
    console.log(data);
    return false; // if you need to cancel submission.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Ward robe">Ward robe <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Lights">Lights <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Fan">Fan <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Fridge">Fridge <br><br><br>
  
    <button type="button" id="rentBtnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```